# pip install error with "-I"

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I use the `pip` to install some package from `virtualenv` environment.
And I get the error,

```
building 'urwid.str_util' extension

/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I -I/Users/dreampuf/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c source/str_util.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/source/str_util.o

source/str_util.c:25:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found

#include <Python.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Then, I try install the package manually.

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/dreampuf/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c source/str_util.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/source/str_util.o
```

The different between the original command from pip and above command is, I remove the single `-I` param, then I can compile it.

How can I fix this? I can't remove the `-I` param for every single compile command.

Comment: @jdotjdot89 
the package is `pip install PACKAGE`, It's the python thirdly module. In my question, `package` means the module of python that I want install.

Comment: No, I totally understood that.  I meant what is the name of your Python module.  `thirdly` sounds like the answer to that question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your response to my comment, since I tried installing a package named 'thirdly' (`pip install thirdly`) and `pip` couldn't find it.  My question is, what is the name of the Python module that you're trying to install, so I can try to replicate the error?

Comment: @jdotjdot89 Oh, it's `pudb`, an gui likely module of pdb.

Comment: @jdotjdot89 Mac OSX lion 10.7.5 And Environment is Homebrew hold the python, I use that as system default python interpreter(through `brew link python`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17845/discussion-between-jdotjdot89-and-dreampuf)